# Running android emulator on travis-ci and Push .apk file

Tags: java, android, testing, appium, travis-ci-cli

I have a problem to push apk file on emulator Android with travis.

This is my config file.

```
script:
 - adb install -r $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/last-app-version/myapp.apk
```

Travis start the process to install apk and i get this in console.

```
[100%] /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk

/home/travis/build/last-app-version/myapp.apk: 1 file pushed. 3.7 MB/s (10766791 bytes in 2.768s)

pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-staging-release.apk
```

After awhile i get this error.

> No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially
>   indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
>   Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on:
>   https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received
>   The build has been terminated

Comment: You found a solution for this?